# In $A=k[[X^2,X^3]]$ no prime power is equal to $(X^3)$

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra

> Let $A=k[[X^2,X^3]]$. Statement: There exists no $\mathfrak p\in \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ s.t. $\mathfrak p^n=(X^3)$.

Is this correct proof?

Assume $\mathfrak p$ is such a prime. Then $A/\mathfrak p\cong k$ as both the generators must then be mapped to $0$ as if $x^3=0$ then $(x^2)^3=0$ so $x^2=0$ as $A/\mathfrak p$ is an integral domain (where $x^3$ and $x^2$ are the images of $X^3$ and $X^2$). So $\mathfrak p=(X^2,X^3)$ (the only max. ideal of $A$) which is a contradiction, as then $n=1$.

Comment: I won't use $A/\mathfrak p$ in order to show that $\mathfrak p=(X^2,X^3)$. It's pretty clear that $X^6=(X^2)^3\in\mathfrak p$ and since $\mathfrak p$ is prime we get $X^2\in\mathfrak p$. Anyway, the last step ($n=1$) needs more details. (Btw, $\mathfrak p^n=(X^{2n},X^{2n+1})$.)

Comment: A remark: usually the indeterminates are denoted by capital letters.